# Apocopes with Santo

Tags: gramática

Why do we use *San* instead of *Santo* before names of saints?

Why do we use *Santo* with saints whose names begin with To- or Do-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Diccionario panhispánico de dudas" says that the general rule is to use "San" before male names of saints, but "Santo" must be used with Domingo, Tomás, Tomé and Toribio.

Comment: They seem to have forgotten to include "San Tolomeo". In this case, the effect caused by a wrong coupling of syllables in oral speech is much worse!